# How to call data target attribute in jquery popup window by php id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDiBW.png)I am developing a Online Library Management system. I have preview button for many books. I have added jquery popupwindow modal to preview my books. The popupwindow is working fine but it's not showing the exact book associated with that button. How to do that? Please help

Below is my button code:

```
<button id="prev" class="btn btn-danger basic-demo_button" data-target="#<?php echo $row['bookid']; ?>" ><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Preview</button>
```

Below is the popup window div:

```
<div id="" class="example_content basic-demo"><?php echo '
            <embed src="assets/img/'.$row['BookSummary'].'"/>'?></div>
                                    </div>
```

And this is the jquery script for popupwindow:

```
<script src="src/popupwindow.js"></script>
<script>

var Demo = (function($, undefined){

  $(function(){
        QuickDemo();
    example2();
    });
  function QuickDemo(){
        $(".basic-demo").PopupWindow({
            autoOpen    : false,
            nativeDrag: false
        });
        $(".basic-demo_button").on("click", function(event){
            $(".basic-demo").PopupWindow("open");
        });
    }
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Now the problem how to get the books by its corresponding id that I have set in the data-target attribute of my button.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a data-id attr to the button:

```
<button id="prev" data-id="<?php echo $row['bookid']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger basic-demo_button" data-target="#<?php echo $row['bookid']; ?>" ><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Preview</button>
```

And then provide a unique id attr to each popup:

```
<div id="basic-demo-<?php echo $row['bookid']?>" class="example_content basic-demo"><?php echo '
        <embed src="assets/img/'.$row['BookSummary'].'"/>'?></div>
                                </div>
```

This should work:

```
$(".basic-demo_button").on("click", function(event){
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $("#basic-demo-"  + id).PopupWindow("open");
});
```

untested. so let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your concern but sadly it's not working. Also the popupwindow is not coming now.

Comment: can you check your console for errors. it should work.

Comment: I am not really good at understanding the console errors.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function
    at Object.dataTable_fun (custom.js:25)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (custom.js:45)
    at c (jquery-1.10.2.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.js:4)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.2.js:4)
    at HTMLDocument.q (jquery-1.10.2.js:4)

This error is visible in every php page of my project. I don't think it's related to this problem.

Comment: @MahnazRafiaIslam that is an unrelated issue. it's related to the dataTable library you're using. try to load this library after jquery or maybe update your question with how you're loading and initializing this library

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Highly-Customizable-jQuery-Popup-Window-Plugin-popupWindow-js.html 

I followed this link for jquery popup window.